# How to remove first & last character of a text?

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, text

I have a record that was converted into text like this:

```
("{""ACC_CODE"":""0/000"",""ACC_DECIMAL"":2}"})
```

I want to remove the `(` and the `)` so that I could convert the text into json.
How do I do that?

Edit: I don't want to use trim function because there are `(` & `)` characters in the original text.

I just want to remove the `first` & `last` character.

Comment: could youplease explain why trim wont fit?..

Comment: @VaoTsun is right: `trim()` should be nearly as efficient as @GordonLinof substr() solution and is more consistent in the sense that it will work even if input lacks outer parentheses.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can do:

```
select substr(col, 2, length(col) - 2)
```

Comment: if col is an expression, there will be some redundant calculation. 
e.g.: substring(substring(test_column, 'abc\.abcd\.id%3D.+?\%3BS\.com') from 30).
Is there a way to avoid calling length() ?

Comment: If rtrim() can specify length, it'll be perfect.

Comment: for ms-sql use `SUBSTRING`

Answer (score 10):

```
t=# select rtrim(ltrim('({()})','('),')');
 rtrim
-------
 {()}
(1 row)
```

ltrim and rtim don't touch brackets inside, like trim itsel:

```
t=# select trim('({()})','()');
 btrim
-------
 {()}
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 5):

To Remove first Character from a string

```
select substr(col, 2)
```

To Remove Last Character from a string

```
select substr(col,1, length(col)-1)
select reverse(substr(reverse(col),2)
```

Answer (score 4):

Function regexp_replace() works for me.

E.g. to remove last 4 chars:

```
select 
regexp_replace('300PRIZE28NOV20183333\%%3BS\.com', '....$', '') campaign_name;

------------------------------
 300PRIZE28NOV20183333\%%3BS\

(1 row)
```

-- more general, remove last 8 chars.

```
select 
regexp_replace('300PRIZE28NOV20183333\%%3BS\.com', '.{8}$', '') campaign_name;
      campaign_name       
--------------------------
 300PRIZE28NOV20183333\%%

(1 row)
```